Determining elementary divisors of a unit group
Currently looking at the following example:
Let $G = (\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Then $G$ is a multiplicative group with cardinality $\varphi(2^4) = 2^3$. The $\mathbb{Z}$-module-structure is given by$i \cdot x = x^i$.
We want to determine the elementary divisors of $G$. The order of every element in  $G$ divides $2^3$, so we get $G = G(2)$. It holds that $  G[2] = \{ x \in G \mid x^2 \equiv 1 \mod 16 \} = \{ \overline1, \overline7, -\overline7, -\overline1 \} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} . $ So we have 2 elementary divisors.
We replace $G$ with $2G = \{ x^2 \mid x \in G \} = \{ \overline1, \overline9 \} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The submodule $2G$ only has the elementary divisor 2. We conclude $  G \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} .$
Now, I understand the individual steps. I just don't get how the last isomorphism follows from having determined the two submodules G[2] and 2G. Could someone explain alongside mentioning the specific results that are used here?

You have an abelian group of order $2^3$. So you know it will be decomposed as a sum of cyclic group of order a power of $2$. What follows is for $p$-groups, or in this case, $2$-groups.
If you have a group of the form $C_{2^{a_1}}\times C_{2^{a_2}}\times\cdots \times C_{2^{a_k}}$, with $a_i\geq 1$, the number of elements of exponent $2$ is $2^k$, which tells you the number of cyclic factors. Your first calculation thus determines the number of factors.
Once you know the number of factors, say $k$, you have
$$G\cong C_{2^{a_1}}\times\cdots\times C_{2^{a_k}},\qquad 1\leq a_1\leq\cdots\leq a_k.$$
Computing $2G$ will tell you how many factors have order exactly $2$. How? Well, because the factors of order exactly $2$ will get "killed" when you compute $2G$. So by comparing the size of $G$ with the size of $2G$, you can figure out how many factors had order exactly $2$. You can then proceed with $4G$ to figure out the number of factors of order at most $4$, etc.
Here, you are looking for a group of order $2^3$. Your first calculation determined that there are two cyclic factors.
(In fact, at this point you can already figure out the structure, since the only way you can have a group of order $2^3$ decomposed as a product of two cyclic $2$-groups is as $C_2\times C_4$, but clearly you are trying to follow the regular process...)
The second calculation determined that $2G$ has order $2$; that tells you that you went from a group with 2 factors to one with exactly one factor. So the decomposition has exactly one factor of order $2$; the other factor is such that half its size is $2$, so the other factor has order $4$. Thus, you get that the decomposition is $C_2\times C_4$.

Very nice, much more explanatory than my answer.

Well, if you're able to use the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, you know that $G$ is isomorphic to one of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{3}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, so you just have to rule out the first and third possibilities.
By the computation of $G[2]$, which is a subgroup of $G$, you know that it can't be $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, because cyclic groups have a unique element of each order dividing the order of the group, whereas you just showed that there are three distinct elements of order $2$.
Meanwhile, by the computation of $2G$, you can see that $G$ can't be isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{3}$, because if it were, then $2G$ would be the trivial group, since every element of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{3}$ is annihilated by $2$.
I don't know if this answer is satisfactory to you, since it doesn't really directly use the power of the theory of elementary divisors. In general, the relationship between $G, 2G$, and $G[2]$ can be expressed via the short exact sequence
$$0 \to G[2] \to G \to 2G \to 0$$
where the first map is given by inclusion, and the second map is given by multiplication by $2$. But I don't think it really helps you directly solve your particular problem. (One note: you can see that this sequence can't be split, because there is no section of the map $G \to 2G$ in this sequence. Indeed, $\overline{9}$ has order $2$, and so any map $2G \to G$ has to send $\overline{9}$ to an element of order dividing $2$, which is necessarily killed by the map $G \to 2G$.)
